# Apache Commons VFS Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, repository, apache-commons, vfs

Any idea on which Maven repository to use in order to use Apache commons VFS libraries?
Thanks.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

** Edit ** : the following repository works fine:

```
    <repository>
        <id>commons-vfs</id>
        <name>Apache Commons VFS Repository Group</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the artifactId ? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2/2.0

Comment: Or it's available as SNAPSHOT : https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~commons-vfs2-distribution

Comment: @nico_ekito You are right: the artifact id was wrong. I corrected it in my question and added the correct Maven repository. Thanks for your help and feel free to add an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please check that your artifactId is correct: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-vfs2/2.0

It should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-vfs2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need version `2.1-SNAPSHOT` you can use this Maven repository:

http://repository.jboss.org/

Version 2.1-SNAPSHOT implements some new features.